# Can we mod android phones using custom bootloader, firmware for MSM8909 Snapdragon 210

Tags: bootloader

Can we mod android phones using custom  bootloader (sbl  secondary bootloader)  , firmware for MSM8909 Snapdragon 210 (phone is zte835). Deleting all factory firmware, bootloader and using custom bootloader and Roms.

I deleted sbl boot files while using qfil and magisk. Phone doesn't turn, it got hard bricked . Bootloader files are corrupted .

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Flashing custom ROMs is not a problem. There are several guides on it specific to your device model. But flashing custom android bootloader is not possible on production devices because it is [protected by secure boot](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/271682/118310) which is permanently enabled in production SoCs by blowing the [eFuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFuse) in the factory. Primary bootloader in Qualcomm Snapdragon SoCs is an immutable image which is burned on the [CPU die](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_(integrated_circuit)) in the factory. This is where infamous Qualcomm's EDL mode resides. As it can't be tampered with, by design it will enforce secure boot up to android bootloader. A hard-bricked device can still boot to EDL mode. You have to flash the factory image to restore images of all partitions.

Comment: When you flash a factory image from EDL mode, it flashes extensible bootloader, android bootloader and all other android partitions. Your question is not specific to your device. If you need help, ask a different question on how to flash a factory image to your device model using EDL mode.

Comment: There's not enough information. It depends on your device model.

Comment: Model is given as zte835 maven

Comment: XDA can help you on this.

Comment: People don't log into xda now a days , are you sure it flashes extensible bootloader, android bootloader and all other android partitions when in edl mode.